# next.js and sass and using :global issues

Tags: sass, next.js

I am using next.js and having an issue with a scss file using "global".

Getting this error:
**Syntax error: Selector ":global .Select-control" is not pure (pure selectors must contain at least one local class or id)**

```
.dropdownColor {
  :global {
    .Select-button {
      border-color: $red-hue-4;
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
:global {
  .Select-control {
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-color: $navy;
  }
  .Select-clear, .Select-arrow {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Do I have to put this in my global scss file? Does the format change?

Comment: you are using "somefile.module.scss" in next.js? CSS modules?

Comment: You cannot use the second code block in "pure" mode. You need to put it in a global stylesheet. Or, as the error mentions, you need to wrap the global selectors in a local classname/ID.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using css modules as it appears you are, this will work to change the border color of an element with a global class of `.Select-button` nested inside your `dropdownColor` module:

```
.dropdownColor {
  :global(.Select-button) {
    border-color: $red-hue-4;
  }
}
```

As the error states, `:global` must be nested inside a local (module) class or id. So while the above works, your second example does not because you have `:global` as a top-level item. Either nest it inside a local id or class like I have done above, or extract it out to a global stylesheet.